# How to get the CloudWatch Agent and Metric Filters to Report Dimensions

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

**Setup**

CloudWatch Agent running on an EC2 instance reports audit logs to CloudWatch. Metric Filter in CloudWatch creates metrics for successful logins, failed logins, ect... when logs are reported.

**Problem**

Metrics created through the Metric Filter does not assign dimensions so I cant query CloudWatch to get a set of metric statistics by InstanceId. This would be extremely useful because I want to know the audit metrics per machine not per log group.

**Comments**

Attaching dimensions is pretty easy using the `put-metric-data` command. I am able to tag the metrics with the dimension for InstanceId and then retrieve only those metrics using `get-metric-statistics`. Is this kind of functionality not possible using the Metric Filters + CloudWatch Agent setup? What would be a possible workaround?

Comment: I've been combing the internet for hours now trying to find a solution to this problem, very frustrating that AWS doesn't give you a way to attach dimensions for a metric filter.  Metric filters aren't very useful without them IMO.

Comment: @markdb314 I was able to work around this issue by posting my own metrics through a lambda function. If I get some time ill put a gist up with how to do it. It works pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you need to do is create a lambda that has an event source set to the log group that you are wanting to create metrics for. I created metric objects that would check each log for certain patterns. The code below is the gist of what you will need to do. I had to rip out some stuff that wasnt applicable. If anyone tries it let me know if it has problems.

I created a lambda (notice the metrics array):

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var Q = require('q');
var cloudwatchAgent = require('cloudwatchAgent');

var metrics = [
{
    "name": "SuccessfulLogins",
    "patterns": ["session opened for user", "successful logon"],
    "dimensionName":"HostName",
    "namespace":"UserStats"
}];

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
var payload = new Buffer(event.awslogs.data, 'base64');

zlib.gunzip(payload, function (e, result) {
if (e) {
  context.fail(e);
} else {
  result = JSON.parse(result.toString('utf-8'));
  console.log('Decoded payload: ', JSON.stringify(result));

metrics.forEach(function (metric) {
        promises.push(cloudwatchAgent.processMetric(metric, result.logStream, result.logEvents));
  });

Q.all(promises).fail(function (error) {
        context.fail('Error processing log events: ' + error);
  }).done(function () {
        context.succeed('Successfully processed log events.');
  });
  }
 });
};
```

That lambda calls this function:

```
var sdk = require('aws-sdk');
var Q = require('q');
var cloudwatch = new sdk.CloudWatch();

function processMetric(metric, streamName, logs) {
console.log('Checking metric ' + metric.name + ' against these patterns:' + metric.patterns.toString());
var deferred = Q.defer();
var value = 0;

logs.forEach(function (logEvent) {
metric.patterns.forEach(function(pattern) {
    if(logEvent.message.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern) > -1) {
    value++;
    }
});
});

var params = {
  MetricData: [{
      MetricName: metric.name,
      Dimensions: [{
          Name: metric.dimensionName,
          Value: streamName
        }],
      Timestamp: new Date(),
      Value: value
    }],
  Namespace: metric.namespace
};

cloudwatch.putMetricData(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
    deferred.reject(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully created metric for ' + metric.name + ' with value ' + value);
    deferred.resolve(data);
  }
});

return deferred.promise;
}

module.exports.processMetric = processMetric;
```